# Error when proguard Android project

Tags: android, ant, proguard

I have Project A which uses Project B as library project. Both of them are using android-support-v4.jar as referenced library. When I try to build the project A with the ant script, which provided by Android SDK, I got the following error at -obfuscate step:

```
[proguard] Preparing output jar [E:\Workspace\GuosenAndroid1.1\bin\proguard\obfuscated.jar]
[proguard]   Copying resources from program jar [E:\Workspace\GuosenAndroid1.1\bin\proguard\original.jar]
[proguard]   Copying resources from program jar [E:\Workspace\GuosenAndroid1.1\libs\android-support-v4.jar]
[proguard] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [android-support-v4.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[proguard]   Copying resources from program jar [E:\Workspace\com_viewpagerindicator\bin\classes.jar]
[proguard] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[proguard]   Copying resources from program jar [E:\Workspace\com_viewpagerindicator\libs\android-support-v4.jar]
[proguard] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [android-support-v4.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
```

BUILD FAILED
E:\Workspace\GuosenAndroid1.1\basicbuild.xml:723: Can't write [E:\Workspace\GuosenAndroid1.1\bin\proguard\obfuscated.jar] (Can't read [E:\Workspace\com_viewpagerindicator\libs\android-support-v4.jar] (Duplicate zip entry [android-support-v4.jar:android/support/v4/content/ModernAsyncTask$WorkerRunnable.class]))

Here is my proguard config:

```
-libraryjars libs/android-support-v4.jar
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep class android.support.** { *; }
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

### Here is the ant script to execute -obfuscate step using Proguard:

```
<target name="-obfuscate">
    <echo>proguard enabled: ${proguard.enabled}</echo>
    <if condition="${proguard.enabled}">
        <then>
            <property name="obfuscate.absolute.dir" location="${out.absolute.dir}/proguard" />
            <property name="preobfuscate.jar.file" value="${obfuscate.absolute.dir}/original.jar" />
            <property name="obfuscated.jar.file" value="${obfuscate.absolute.dir}/obfuscated.jar" />
            <!-- input for dex will be proguard's output -->
            <property name="out.dex.input.absolute.dir" value="${obfuscated.jar.file}" />

            <!-- Add Proguard Tasks -->
            <property name="proguard.jar" location="${android.tools.dir}/proguard/lib/proguard.jar" />
            <taskdef name="proguard" classname="proguard.ant.ProGuardTask" classpath="${proguard.jar}" />

            <!-- Set the android classpath Path object into a single property. It'll be
                 all the jar files separated by a platform path-separator.
                 Each path must be quoted if it contains spaces.
            -->
            <pathconvert property="android.libraryjars" refid="android.target.classpath">
                <firstmatchmapper>
                    <regexpmapper from='^([^ ]*)( .*)$$' to='"\1\2"'/>
                    <identitymapper/>
                </firstmatchmapper>
            </pathconvert>

            <!-- Build a path object with all the jar files that must be obfuscated.
                 This include the project compiled source code and any 3rd party jar
                 files. -->
            <path id="project.jars.ref">
                <pathelement location="${preobfuscate.jar.file}" />
                <path refid="jar.libs.ref" />
            </path>
            <!-- Set the project jar files Path object into a single property. It'll be
                 all the jar files separated by a platform path-separator.
                 Each path must be quoted if it contains spaces.
            -->
            <pathconvert property="project.jars" refid="project.jars.ref">
                <firstmatchmapper>
                    <regexpmapper from='^([^ ]*)( .*)$$' to='"\1\2"'/>
                    <identitymapper/>
                </firstmatchmapper>
            </pathconvert>

            <mkdir   dir="${obfuscate.absolute.dir}" />
            <delete file="${preobfuscate.jar.file}"/>
            <delete file="${obfuscated.jar.file}"/>
            <jar basedir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
                destfile="${preobfuscate.jar.file}" />
            <proguard>
                @${proguard.config}
                -injars       ${project.jars}
                -outjars      "${obfuscated.jar.file}"
                -libraryjars  ${android.libraryjars}
                -dump         "${obfuscate.absolute.dir}/dump.txt"
                -printseeds   "${obfuscate.absolute.dir}/seeds.txt"
                -printusage   "${obfuscate.absolute.dir}/usage.txt"
                -printmapping "${obfuscate.absolute.dir}/mapping.txt"
            </proguard>
        </then>
    </if>
```

What should I do to get rid of this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`android-support-v4.jar` is being included twice in the set of code that Proguard is optimizing, and this isn't allowed. Do you have the android support jar included in two places? That is what it really looks like from your error message. I think you're missing a line where it says where the other occurrence is in your project.

Comment: @Samuel Can you post your solution? I'm having this problem right now.

Comment: @Samuel, can you please post your solution so that other can solve their problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar problem. I'm using viewpagerindicator library, it has a dependency to android support library v4, i'm using android appcompat as well and it has the same dependency.

So I exclude the support library dependency from viewpagerindicator in Gradle like this:

```
compile ('fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1') {
    // exclude redundant transitive dependency
    exclude (group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4')
}
```